# Substring match in MySQL columns

Tags: mysql

I have a `users` table with a column name `competences,` and this column has comma separated values like "IT, Web Development, App Development."

For e.g.

```
id | username | Competences
 1 |    abc   | IT, Web Development, App Development
 2 |    xyz   | Graphics, App Development
```

Now, I have another search string like "Web Development, iOS Development". I need to get all the users where competences column has any substring(in between the commas) of a search string.

If search string is `Web Development, iOS Development`

Result should be:

```
id | username | Competences
 1 |    abc   | IT, Web Development, App Development
```

I am expecting this result because `Web Development` is a part of the search string and also a part of `competences` column.

Comment: Look up the `*~` operator

Comment: Where/how do you build the search string? 

You could split on comma (,) and for each instance you could add 'Or competences like %' + string(n) + '%'. 
Be careful of SQL injections

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Web Development', Competences) AND  FIND_IN_SET('App Development', Competences)`  You will find that FIND_IN_SET work better on comma separated values.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland. I'll write some custom code in PHP file to generate this query.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE Competences LIKE '%Web Development%'  AND Competences LIKE '%App Development%'`

Comment: Try this:     SELECT * FROM table123 WHERE Competences LIKE '%Web Development%' OR Competences LIKE '%App Development%'